# SAPUI5 Complex data binding example with DropdownBox in XML view

Tags: xml, json, data-binding, sapui5

I built this JSON (tested as valid) (.. don't mind that men and women are named the same here :-)):

```
{
    "staff": {
        "berlin": [{
            "male": [
                {"firstName": "Lasse", "lastName": "Larsson"},  
                {"firstName": "Gerrit", "lastName": "Gartner"}
            ],
            "female": [
                {"firstName": "Lasse", "lastName": "Larsson"},  
                {"firstName": "Gerrit", "lastName": "Gartner"}
            ]
        }],
        "paris": [{
            "male": [
                {"firstName": "Lasse", "lastName": "Larsson"},  
                {"firstName": "Gerrit", "lastName": "Gartner"}
            ],
            "female": [
                {"firstName": "Lasse", "lastName": "Larsson"},  
                {"firstName": "Gerrit", "lastName": "Gartner"}
            ]
        }],
        "oslo": [{
            "male": [
                {"firstName": "Lasse", "lastName": "Larsson"},  
                {"firstName": "Gerrit", "lastName": "Gartner"}
            ],
            "female": [
                {"firstName": "Lasse", "lastName": "Larsson"},  
                {"firstName": "Gerrit", "lastName": "Gartner"}
            ]
        }]
    }
}
```

In my controller I set the JSON model to the whole view like this:

```
// init instance of JSON model
this.staffData = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
// load JSON file into model
this.staffData.loadData("ajax-dummy/staff.json");
// bind model to whole view 
this.getView().setModel(this.staffData);
```

In my XML view I would now like to dynamically build a (nested) DropdownBox 
which should make me select e.g. 
berlin->male->lastName
So I need 3 levels of ListItems.

The first problem is: I could generate this with JS (build one Listitem for each
key in the staff object etc.) but I have no idea how to deal with this in the XML view.
It looks like this at the moment:

```
<content>
<DropdownBox id="dd-locations" editable="true">
<core:ListItem text="{/staff/berlin}"></core:ListItem>
</DropdownBox>
</content>
```

And it displays (of course) just *"{object ..}"* in den DropdownBox, because it IS an object.

Is this even possible to build within the XML view with data binding? Or is there a better way to structure
the JSON? I know the ListItems need an array... And finally:  How can I nest the ListItems? Is there a better Control
then DropdownBox I should use?

EDIT: 
What I want to have is "just" nesting Listitems like I could in HTML. I tried e.g.:

```
<ComboBox>
                            <items>
                                <core:ListItem key="key2" text="text2"/>
                                <core:ListItem key="key3" text="text2">
                                    <ComboBox>
                                        <items>
                                            <core:ListItem key="key4" text="text3"/>
                                            <core:ListItem key="key5" text="text3"/>
                                            <core:ListItem key="key6" text="text3"/>
                                         </items>
                                    </ComboBox>
                                </core:ListItem>
                                <core:ListItem key="key4" text="text2"/>
                             </items>
                        </ComboBox>
```

But hen an error occurs which says:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot add direct child without default aggregation
>   defined for control sap.ui.core.ListItem

How can I define an item aggregation for a ListItem? Would that work?

Thanks a lot, ho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it is a desirable approach in your case, but given the hierarchical nature of your model, maybe this example of a "Table - Breadcrumb" is what you're looking for:    https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TableBreadcrumb/preview
It allows you to 'drill deeper' into your model hierarchy, and step back up if needed too

But I'm not sure if it can be adapted to a 'multi-level dropdownbox' though...

EDIT: I had a more thorough look at your JSON, and it seems the structure is not correct.
To supply data to multiple dropdowns, the data should be in Array format, not Object format. Right now, your JSON contains a property `staff` with multiple properties `berlin`, `paris`, etc, whereas it should be an array of cities. I have modified your JSON so the `staff` property contains an array of objects, which contains a `gender` property containing an array of objects, which contains a `person` property containing an array of objects.

Furthermore, in order to supply the correct binding to the "child" dropdowns, you could set the binding to the correct path upon selecting a entry from the dropdown.

See the below working snippet for the restructured model (an array of cities, an array of genders and an array of people), and the rebinding of dropdowns:

```js
sap.ui.controller("view1.initial", {
    onInit : function(oEvent) {
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oModel.setData({
            "staff": [
                {
                    "city" : ""
                },
                {
                    "city" : "berlin",
                    "genders" : [
                        { 
                            "gender" : "male", 
                            "people" : [
                                {"firstName": "Lasse", "lastName": "Larsson"},  
                                {"firstName": "Gerrit", "lastName": "Gartner"}
                            ]
                        },
                        { 
                            "gender" : "female", 
                            "people" : [
                                {"firstName": "Paris", "lastName": "Hilton"},  
                                {"firstName": "Kate", "lastName": "Upton"}
                            ]
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "city" : "paris",
                    "genders" : [
                        { 
                            "gender" : "male", 
                            "people" : [
                                {"firstName": "Lasse", "lastName": "Larsson"},  
                                {"firstName": "Gerrit", "lastName": "Gartner"}
                            ]
                        },
                        { 
                            "gender" : "female", 
                            "people" : [
                                {"firstName": "Lasse", "lastName": "Larsson"},  
                                {"firstName": "Gerrit", "lastName": "Gartner"}
                            ]
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "city" : "oslo",
                    "genders" : [
                        { 
                            "gender" : "male", 
                            "people" : [
                                {"firstName": "Lasse", "lastName": "Larsson"},  
                                {"firstName": "Gerrit", "lastName": "Gartner"}
                            ]
                        },
                        { 
                            "gender" : "female", 
                            "people" : [
                                {"firstName": "Lasse", "lastName": "Larsson"},  
                                {"firstName": "Gerrit", "lastName": "Gartner"}
                            ]
                        },
                    ]
                },
            ]
        });
        this.getView().setModel(oModel);

    },

    handleStaffSelect : function(oEvent) {
        var oGender = this.byId("selGender");
        var oTemplate = new sap.ui.core.ListItem({ key : "{gender}", text : "{gender}"})
        oGender.bindItems(oEvent.getParameter("selectedItem").getBindingContext().getPath() + "/genders", oTemplate);
    },

    handleGenderSelect : function(oEvent) {
        var oGender = this.byId("selPerson");
        var oTemplate = new sap.ui.core.ListItem({ key : "{lastName}", text : "{lastName}"})
        oGender.bindItems(oEvent.getParameter("selectedItem").getBindingContext().getPath() + "/people", oTemplate);
    }
});

sap.ui.xmlview("main", {
    viewContent: jQuery("#view1").html()
})
.placeAt("uiArea");
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>

<div id="uiArea"></div>

<script id="view1" type="ui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View 
      controllerName="view1.initial"
      xmlns="sap.m"
      xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
      xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
        <Select id="selStaff" items="{/staff}" change="handleStaffSelect">
            <core:ListItem key="{city}" text="{city}" />
        </Select>
        <Select id="selGender" change="handleGenderSelect" />
        <Select id="selPerson" />
    </mvc:View>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - this could be an option theoretically, but I do want to explore the possibilities for working with dDropdownBox/ComboBox. (I edited by question to be more clear what I want)

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort to enlighten me. This is exactly what I was looking for from the logically point of view. Great. And finally, your approach (updating dependent selects) is even more "elegant" than nesting elements.